# Perforce directory structure

Tags: directory, mapping, perforce, vcs-checkout

In Perforce, I notice that my work-space is linked to a specific directory (location) in my local hard drive. Is it possible to change the location of this mapping for each file? For example if I have two scripts in two completely different directories locally -

C:/File1.pl & D:/File2.pl

And I want to map these 2 scripts under the same folder in perforce. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root directory must be the same for all files in a single workspace.

However, you can define multiple workspaces, one which resides on your C:\ disk and one which resides on your D:\ disk.

Generally, a single workspace is used for a single project, and generally all files for a single project are located together in a single area of your workstation. I'm having trouble thinking of a scenario in which you'd want to have files be part of a single project, and yet stored in various places scattered around your workstation. Can you explain your scenario further?

There are techniques (the SUBST command, using Windows Junction Points, etc.) which can be used to create aliases for files on a different disk, but given what you've described, using multiple workspaces seems like the clearest approach to me.

Comment: Yes, creating multiple work spaces for different projects will be the way to go. Thanks for the response !